# objective-c "generic" type for @property for use with multiple subclasses

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i'm not sure of the most eloquent way to state this but i will give it my best. i have created a custom class that is a generic object with some properties. i have created a couple subclasses to extend that and make them more specific than the superclass. so for the sake of example i will throw out some generic example code that may or may not be proper syntax only to illustrate what i would like to accomplish.

```
@interface Vehicle : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int wheels;

- (id)initWithNumberOfWheels:(int)wheels;

@end
```

from there i create some subclasses for same "car" & "truck" which give more detail to the class.

```
@interface Car : Vehicle

@property (nonatomic) BOOL convertible;
@property etc...

@end
```

and...

```
@interface Truck : Vehicle

@property (nonatomic) BOOL is4x4;
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfDoors;

@end
```

so here is where it gets interesting. i want to create another class that allocates those objects but i want the "type" of vehicle to be determined in the init method but use the same @property variable. so for example (and again, this is all garbage code just to give a visual representation)

Road.h

```
#import "Car.h"
#import "Truck.h"

@interface Road : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NotSureWhatToUseHereToMakeThisWork *myRide;
// doesn't work: @property (strong, nonatomic) id myRide; 
// doesn't work: @property (strong, nonatomic) Vehicle *myRide; 


- (id)initWithCars;
- (id)initWithTrucks;

@end
```

Road.m

```
@implementation Road

- (id)initWithCars
{
//standard init code...

    myRide = [[Car alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:4];
    myRide.convertable = NO;
}

- (id)initWithTrucks
{
//standard init code...

    myRide = [[Truck alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:6]; 
//yes, some trucks have more than 4 wheels

    myRide.is4x4 = YES;
}

@end
```

the bottom line is if i use the superclass in the @property it doesn't get the subclass properties obviously. basically i want to keep all this as generic and reusable as possible. it doesn't make since to make a special "road" class just for cars & one for trucks. a road is a road after all. is there anyway to do what i am after? is there a better way to do something like this? the primary purpose is to have objects that inherit specific properties  for specific situations only. the reason i don't want to make extra @properties is i don't want those visible if they aren't applicable to the situation.

edit:
i added a couple extra snippets to show what i tried before even posting this question that didn't work.

answer: the correct "answer" if anyone is curious is located in CRD's response in the "Addendum". the reason this works is the type "id" can only call methods and does not inherit properties. so rather the workaround (i say it that way, as i was researching this, came to the conclusion this is not good programming and should probably be avoid if possible) would be to use the accessor methods to get/set the property.

```
id mySomethingObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init...];
[mySomethingObject setPropertyMethod]...; //sets value
[mySomethingObject propertyMethod]...; //gets value
```

rather than trying to use...

```
mySomethingObject.property = ; //set
mySomethingObject.property; //get
```

as stated in the correct answer, if your class you allocated "id" to does not respond to that method your program will crash.

Comment: Use `id` or `NSObject*` or `Vehicle*`.  The latter is generally preferred since it's the most specific that "encloses" the others.  For simplicity have all your Vehicles implement a "type" method to return what they are, from a specific enum or such -- this is simpler than always testing isKindOfClass.

Comment: i appreciate all the suggestions, unfortunately the main reason for me posting this question is i have tried all the offered suggestions with no luck. @HotLicks if i use "id" the compiler gives and error "Property "whatevermypropertynameis" not found on object type 'id'."

Comment: Did you see my answer?  You cast to the target type before making a reference to methods or properties of that specific type.

Comment: @HotLicks feel free to type out an exact syntax of code to elaborate, because if you read through my other comments your suggestion doesn't work. the end "myRide" object has none of the "Car" or "Truck" properties available when doing the way you suggest.

Comment: You didn't do it the way I suggested then.  You have to test the type and cast to the appropriate class based on that, before referencing type-specific interfaces.

Comment: Dos, the folks who you're interacting with here likely have a combined programming experience in excess of 100 years.  They know what they're talking about.  You don't.

Comment: @HotLicks apparently i do know what i am talking about because i have already confirmed through here and as well as a software development firm that specializes in ios development that what i was trying to do just can't be done in objective-c. the way i was going about it is more of a java, c#, etc approach and not suited for objective-c.

Comment: That's odd -- there's hardly anything that you can do in Java that can't be done in Objective-C, by hook or by crook.

Comment: @DoS: would you mind to show us example code of what you are talking of in Java, C# or whatever? Maybe than we understand you or can explain you better what you got wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks, how can I subclass some generic type while preserving its generic property? This is easy in Java; in Objective-C I can only do this by overriding all the methods I need, but they are just trivially calling the same method on super class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be confusing a number of issues.

First there is the type of an instance vs. the type of variables which hold references to instances. When an object is created is it of some specific type and that types does **not** change[*]. Variables also have a type, and that does not change either. Subtyping/inheritance allows you to store a reference to an object of some type, `T`, in a variable of some other type, `S`, provided `S` is a supertype of `T`.

Second there is static vs. dynamic typing. While Objective-C uses dynamic typing, where the actual type of objects used in some operation is determined at run time, the compiler itself uses static typing, where types are determined during compilation, to aid in writing correct programs. Sometimes the compilers static checking will just produce warnings, but in other cases the compiler will refuse to compile something. In particular *property* references are compiled based on static typing.

In your example this means you cannot *directly* reference a property of `Car` on an object referenced by a variable of type `Vehicle *`, even if you know the referenced object is a `Car` - as at compile time all that is known is that is it a `Vehicle`.

The solution is to first test the actual type of the referenced object and then introduce a local variable of the more precise type, or use a lot of casts. For example:

```
// (a) create an object of type Car (for a Reliant Robin ;-))
// (b) create a variable of type Car and store in it a reference to the created Car
Car *myCar = [[Car alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:3];

// Create a variable of type Vehicle and store in it the reference stored in myCar
// The created instance is *still* a Car
Vehicle *myRide = myCar;

// See if myRide is a Car and then do something
if ([myRide isKindOfClass:Car.class])
{
    // create a variable of type Car to avoid having to continually cast myRide
    Car *myCarRide = (Car *)myRide; // due to if above we know this cast is valid

    if (myCarRide.isConvertible) ...
```

To do this without the intermediate variable you use a cast:

```
...
// See if myRide is a Car and then do something
if ([myRide isKindOfClass:Car.class])
{
    if (((Car *)myCarRide).isConvertible) ...
```

Which shows why the intermediate variable approach is better!

As a final example, you write your `initWithTrucks` method like this:

```
- (id)initWithTrucks
{
   //standard init code...

   Truck *myTruck = [[Truck alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:6]; 
   //yes, some trucks have more than 4 wheels
   myTruck.is4x4 = YES;

   // Store the reference to the created Truck in myRide
   myRide = myTruck;
}
```

HTH

**Addendum**

From your comments it seems you may be looking for dynamic typing and do not wish to the compiler to perform any static typing. This is (partially) supported, but not using the dot notation for properties - you must use the getter and setter methods directly.

First, in `Road` you declare `myRide` to be type `id`:

```
@interface Road : NSObject

@property id myRide;
```

The `id` type means two things (a) any object reference and (b) do not statically check a method exists on the object. *However* the compiler must know that a called method exists on *some* object, and it will still perform static type checks on the arguments to the method - so its not complete dynamic typing (however you could pass `id` typed expressions or declare your methods to take arguments of type `id` of course...).

Second you make all references to properties use the getter or setter methods directly and do not use the dot notation (for non-property methods you just call them as usual). E.g.:

```
- (id)initWithTrucks
{
   //standard init code...

   myRide = [[Truck alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:6]; 
   //yes, some trucks have more than 4 wheels
   [myRide setIs4x4:YES];
}
```

If you make a call such as `[myRide setIs4x4:YES]` and `myRide` is referencing a `Car` object then you will get a runtime error.

The general recommendation is to stick as much as possible with the compiler's static typechecking.

[*] We will ignore any runtime magic, there be dragons. In normal code objects never change type.

Comment: i am not confusing anything, and your answer is exactly what i didn't want to do. i know i could just have "myCar = ..." & "myTruck = ..." but as i said in the questions thats not what i am after. apparently the simple answer to this question is "no. objective-c doesn't let you do that". i wanted to keep it generic so any class allocating and then referencing my object would use "myRide" wether its a "Car" or a "Truck". this was simply to keep code reusable and more for proof of concept. but again, your answer sums it up best. it can't be done that way.

Comment: for @DoS: No, it cant be done in Objective-C [ * ], you cannot switch from one class to another (* for all others: yes, indeed it CAN be done: just use the common base class or protocol and use introspection to get runtime infos about the real object.)

Comment: @vikingosegundo thanks again, i had a feeling i was heading down a dead end but just wanted to get confirmation from the pros.

Comment: @DoS: did you ever saw something like you desire in any other language. Switching variable types? I never did. the rule is: you can assign that type or an subtype. but you wont change the type of the variable by assigning a subtype. and that doesnt mater, as a car is a vehicle, and a truck as-well.

Comment: @DoS - It sounds like you want dynamic typing and runtime errors, I've added an Addendum. HTH.

Comment: @CRD: While you are right, looking at the other answers and DoS' comments he just refuses to accept this. He is dreaming of some kind of switching property, while the normal OO Design would be to type the property with a more general type (super class) that accepts all possible sub-classes. As he does not understand, that a sub-class doesnt change it's type when assigned to a variable of a more general type, he can't see that it is exactly what he needs.

Comment: @CRD unfortunately i stumbled up the answer before i had a chance to come back and check your addendum. you're answer is correct however and is pretty much what i came up with.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the type "Vehicle" and then cast your object with "Truck" or "Car" to get the specific properties

Comment: You still need to cast (either to `id`, or to `Car`) to avoid a compiler warning when calling `Car`-specific methods regardless of the (runtime) check that the object is a `Car`.

Answer (score 3):

the most generic architecture would be to create a `VehicleProtocol`, that any class could implement. you still could have a Vehicle class that implements the protocol and subclass from it (similar to NSObject implementing the NSObject protocol), or let independent classes implement it. the road would have a property `@property (strong) id<VehicleProtocol> myRide`.

---

A complete example of the later architecture: no vehicle super class, but all a VehicleProtocol

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@protocol VehicleProtocol <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger wheels;
@end

@interface Car : NSObject <VehicleProtocol>
@property (nonatomic) BOOL convertible;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger wheels;
-(id)initWithNumberOfWheels:(NSUInteger) numberOfWheels;
@end

@implementation Car
-(id)initWithNumberOfWheels:(NSUInteger) numberOfWheels
{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _wheels = numberOfWheels;
    }
    return self;
}
@end


@interface Truck : NSObject <VehicleProtocol>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL is4x4;
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfDoors;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger wheels;
-(id)initWithNumberOfWheels:(NSUInteger) numberOfWheels;

@end

@implementation Truck
-(id)initWithNumberOfWheels:(NSUInteger) numberOfWheels
{

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _wheels = numberOfWheels;
    }
    return self;
}
@end




@interface Road : NSObject
@property (strong) id<VehicleProtocol> myRide;
@end

@implementation Road
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *vehicles =  @[[[Car alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:4], [[Car alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:3], [[Truck alloc] initWithNumberOfWheels:10]] ;

        for (id v in vehicles) {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[Truck class]]) {
                [v setIs4x4:YES];
            }
        }


        Road *road = [[Road alloc] init];
        road.myRide = vehicles[0];
        NSLog(@"%@", road.myRide);


        road.myRide = vehicles[2];
        NSLog(@"%@", road.myRide);

        NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
        road.myRide = obj; // warning in this line
        NSLog(@"%@", road.myRide);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sure it might have more lines of codes than with "classical subclassing", but there are less dependencies. Instead the classes agree on a contract to fulfill. Here the contract only requires the objects to have any number of wheels.

Note that I create a Road and assign first a car and than a truck (I also show how to identify cars and trucks via `-isKindOfClass:`), both works without any warning or error, as Car and Truck completely fulfill the contract. Than I assign a plain NSObject. Here the compiler warns, as he recognizes that NSObject does not implement the protocol. Though it is not an compiler error, as the compiler does not know, if you will use any protocol specific method on that object.

In case of a plain NSObject assigned to myRide, this line

```
NSLog(@"%@ %ld", road.myRide, (unsigned long)road.myRide.wheels);
```

will lead to a runtime crash (as an NSObject instance does not respond to wheel) — but at compile time it will not even trigger a warning.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response, unfortunately my real world code is for more complex then the sample code i posted. having that many protocol methods for all the properties would get unwieldily.

Comment: as I said: you can mix sub classing and protocols. with a certain degree of complexity there will be no other elegant way, as objective-c has no multi-inheritance. also protocols are great for defining modules and their interfaces.

Comment: btw: I am also a real world coder and make my money with working on real world codes.

Answer (score 1):

Storing a Car in a variable of type `Vehicle *` does not remove the object's Car properties — the Car will still be able to access all of its state normally — it just means that you can't access the properties through that variable.

But that's the basic idea here, isn't it? You want this class to be able to handle all Vehicles, and that's what it's doing — it's only showing you the functionality available to all Vehicles. So you can have the interface necessary for interaction with a generic Vehicle in the Vehicle class, and implement the methods in your subclasses to do the class-appropriate behavior when called, and everything will work.

If the issue is specifically creating new instances of a specific class that you want to treat generically from that point on, you can use a statically typed local variable and assign to the generically typed variable once it's set up.

For example, let's say we have a game where there are human players and AI players, and the human player can give himself an advantage by making AI players take more damage. We could do this:

```
@interface Combatant : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic) int hitPoints;

- (void)takeDamage:(int)damageAmount;
@end

@implementation Combatant
- (void)takeDamage:(int)damageAmount {
    self.hitPoints -= damageAmount;
}
@end

@interface HumanCombatant : Combatant
@property(nonatomic, strong) UserID *userID;
- (id)initWithUserID:(UserID *)theID;
@end

@implementation HumanCombatant
- (id)initWithUserID:(UserID *)theID {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _userID = [theID retain];
    }
}

- (void)takeDamage:(int)damageAmount {
    [super takeDamage: damageAmount];
    NSLog(@"Human took %d damage, has %d health remaining", damageAmount, self.hitPoints);
}
@end

@interface AICombatant : Combatant
@property(nonatomic) double damageMultiplier;
@end

@implementation AICombatant
- (void)takeDamage:(int)damageAmount {
    int modifiedDamage = damageAmount * self.damageMultiplier;
    [super takeDamage: modifiedDamage];
    NSLog("AI took %d damage, has %d health remaining", modifiedDamage, self.hitPoints);
}
@end
```

Then, in most of our game code, we can use a variable typed as a `Combatant *`, and when you send it `takeDamage:`, it will do the right thing for the type of combatant it is. Our external code that calls the object a `Combatant *` will not be able to directly access an AICombatant's `damageMultiplier` property, because the other code doesn't know whether the Combatant is an AICombatant, but the object will still have that property and will behave correctly for its class.

Comment: Make the variable `Vehicle*`, have Vehicle implement a `type` method, do a `switch` or `if` on `type` to do type-specific stuff (after casting to the appropriate specific class).  Once you cast to the specific type the type-specific methods are accessible.

Comment: @HotLicks: I would do that as a last resort, but it is often a code smell. Method dispatch is already a giant type-specialized switch table, so whenever possible I prefer to hide the type-specific stuff behind generalized methods. (E.g. instead of `if (target.type == AIPlayer) damage *= 1.2; target.hitPoints -= damage;` I'd just have all possible targets implement `takeDamage:` and apply their multiplier as needed.

Comment: To paraphrase Einstein, make as much stuff generic as possible, but no more.

Comment: @Chuck your suggestion doesn't work because you do in fact lose the "car" properties. if store it as "Vehicle *myRide" i am able to access the vehicle properties but properties like "myRide.convertable" are not accessible. from my understanding a superclass does not know anything about its subclasses. inheritance is a one way street. by storing as "Vehicle *" there is no way for the Vehicle class to implement the subclass properties, or at least thats what i am finding. and just to be clear, and not meant to be a jerk, i've tried your solution and it in fact does not work.

Comment: @DoS: No, you do not "lose" the properties — the properties *are there*, but the compiler just doesn't let you access them with dot notation through that variable. The object itself is still a Car and still has those properties. Typing the variable as `Vehicle *` tells the compiler "I am going to treat this object as a generic Vehicle, so only let me use messages and properties declared in the Vehicle interface." But if the object is a Car, it will still respond as a Car. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @DoS: I added an example to give a better idea of what I'm saying.

Comment: @DoS: If you create a Car but save or access it as Vehicle it still is a Car. and in the instance of car — also called object of type Care — is no superclass hidden. everything the Car overwrites is in that object exactly once: their overwritten method or property. even if you treat it like a Vehicle or even Truck, the object stays a car and will responds with the implementations found in the class car. I have to say: you are missing fundamentals on OOP. Please check your literature again.

Comment: @DoS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/OOP_ObjC.pdf

Comment: @vikingosegundo you might be missing what its is i am doing. i am not overwriting any methods or properties of the superclass in the subclass. i am "extending" the superclass to make it more specific to the object needed. the same concept can apply to a "Dog" class and then a "Bulldog" subclass. if i subclass "Dog" i'm not going to overwrite and the "walk" & "shit" methods. a bulldog & a poodle walk and shit the same way but their "fur" property will be different. i think you might be looking at what i want to do backwards...

Comment: @vikingosegundo feel free to write your own code on this, but i can assure you if i store something as "Vehicle" or "Dog" and then allocate it as "Car" or "Boxer", you will not be able to access the "Car" properties of that object and the compiler will balk.

Comment: @Chuck thanks for the splendid example. i think i may have came across the main difference in concepts. the examples and suggestions given are not allocating and initializing a new object with that specific variable name. i think thats where the problem lays. ultimately i want "*myThing" to be either of type "Car" or "Truck" depending on the initialization. quite frankly at this point don't think thats even possible to do... and yes i know you don't "lose" properties, i was just trying to keep my comment short and not have to type "lose the ability to access..."

Comment: @vikingosegundo just an fyi, not trying to be an a-hole and appreciate the input. i have a feeling we are talking about two different topics. my last comment directed to Chuck i think explains it.

Comment: @DoS: just make your property of the class vehicle. you can assign any subclass of vehicle to it and than use introspection to find out, what subclass' object you got. for example as I showed it in my code with `-isKindOfClass:`

Comment: @DoS - You simply are not understanding.  When you do `[[Truck alloc] init]`, what you get back is a Truck.  Storing it in a pointer typed `id` or `NSObject*` or `Vehicle*` does not change the object itself, and as soon as you put (cast) it back into the "correct" type of pointer (ie, `Truck*`) the compiler will happily let you access the Truck-specific methods and properties.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `Vehicle*` and make each class implement `type` to return a constant indicating that class's type.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Vehicle* yourRide;
...
if (yourRide.type == VehicleConstant_Truck) {
  Truck* yourTruck = (Truck*) yourRide;
  NSLog(@"This truck %s a 4x4", yourTruck.is4x4 ? "is" : "isn't");
}
```

To make @vikingosegundo happy, an alternative approach is to do:

```
if ([yourRide isKindOfClass:[Truck class]]) {
```

instead of the `if` statement above.

Comment: why not just check for the Class?

Comment: You can check the class, but it's a hair more involved and less intuitive.

Comment: but maintaining the type property while you have the class type is unnecessary redundancy. so I'd call your approach much less intuitive and smelly. And if I am subclassing a class I dont own the code of, it gets real messy.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Yeah, there are arguments both ways.